# Proofing transitivity of simulation relation in Kripke structures

Tags: logic, proof-writing, kripke-models

I would like to proof transitivity of simulation in Kripke Structures.

Proof Sketch:

Let A, B, C be Kripke Structures, with
A=(Sa,S0a,Ra,AP,La) 
B=(Sb,S0b,Rb,AP,Lb)
C=(Sc,S0c,Rc,AP,Lc)

H ⊆ S × S′ is simulation relation between M and M′ iff for every (s, s′) ∈ H: 
s and s′ satisfy the same propositions 
For every successor t such that (s, t) ∈ R, there is a corresponding successor t such that(s’,t’) ∈ R’ and(t,t’)∈H 
For every initial state s ∈ S0 there is a corresponding initial state s′ ∈ S′0 such that (s, s′) ∈ H

Let R be the simulation relation (A is simulated by B), show that 
A R B ^ B R C => A R C

Assume A R B, by definition A and B satisfy the same propositions, then for each transition (sa,ta) ∈ Ra, there is a corresponding state (sb,tb) ∈ Rb and for each initial state  sa ∈ S0a, there is an initial state sb ∈ S0b.

Assume B R C, by definition A and B satisfy the same propositions, then for each transition (sb,tb) ∈ Ra, there is a corresponding state (sc,tc) ∈ Rb and for each initial state  sb ∈ S0b, there is an initial state sc ∈ S0c.

Then continue by contraposition, but I don't know how to proceed. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the definition of "A is simulated by B", which means that **there exists** a simulation relation H between the states of A and those of B. This definition will be absolutely essential in any proof of the proposition you want. In particular, your proof will need to show how a simulation relation H between A and B and another simulation relation H' between B and C can be used to produce a simulation relation between A and C.